# Regex for words which consist tags in between

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a content. I have divided the paragraph into different lines so that I can explain clearly.

```
 <p>The most 
 i<del class="del" editid="6">m</del>por<ins class="ins">sss</ins>t<del class="del>a</del>n<ins class="ins">sss</ins>t 
 reso<del class="del">ur</del>ce 
 for all develo<ins class="ins">vvv</ins>pers 
 working with , 
 integratin<del class="del">g i</del>t
 with their 
 <ins class="ins">ssss</ins>w<ins class="ins">ss</ins><del class="del">e</del><ins class="ins">ss</ins>bsi<del class="del">te</del>s 
 and applications, 
 an<ins class="ins">sss</ins>d<del class="del"> </del>customizing
 to their needs. You can start from here.
```

In this I have words which contain `<del></del> and <ins></ins> tags` in between the words. Each word has any number of `<del></del> and <ins></ins> tags` tags.

I am trying to write a regex which identifies the words which consist of these `<del></del> and <ins></ins> tags`.

For a note, regex which highlights only the words with `<del></del> and <ins></ins> tags`. The word may start with a letter or a `<del>` tag or `<ins>` tag and it may also end with letter or a `<del>` tag or `<ins>` tag

Here a word means it must start after a space and until it finds a space(space not between `<del> and <ins> tags or space not between the words inside the <del></del> and <ins></ins> tags`)

For example in the content the words are

```
  i<del class="del" editid="6">m</del>por<ins class="ins">sss</ins>t<del class="del>a</del>n<ins class="ins">sss</ins>t 

  reso<del class="del">ur</del>ce

  integratin<del class="del">g i</del>t

  <ins class="ins">ssss</ins>w<ins class="ins">ss</ins><del class="del">e</del><ins class="ins">ss</ins>bsi<del class="del">te</del>s

  an<ins class="ins">sss</ins>d<del class="del"> </del>customizing
```

How to write a regex to identify words with such conditions. Please help.

Comment: Have you tried any?

Comment: @Rao  I am very new to regex. I tried something, I guess which is not correct https://regex101.com/r/wJ9rL3/1. It is not identifying all the cases, specially the words which have multiple <ins> and <del> tags

Answer (score 0):

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/cE4mE3/1)

```js
text = ['<p>The most '
    ,' i<del class="del" editid="6">m</del>por<ins class="ins">sss</ins>t<del class="del>a</del>n<ins class="ins">sss</ins>t '
    ,' reso<del class="del">ur</del>ce '
    ,' for all develo<ins class="ins">vvv</ins>pers '
    ,' working with , '
    ,' integratin<del class="del">g i</del>t'
    ,' with their '
    ,' <ins class="ins">ssss</ins>w<ins class="ins">ss</ins><del class="del">e</del><ins class="ins">ss</ins>bsi<del class="del">te</del>s '
    ,' and applications, '
    ,' an<ins class="ins">sss</ins>d<del class="del"> </del>customizing'
    ,' to their needs. You can start from here.'
].join('\n');
text.match(/(\s|^)(\S{0,}<(del|ins).*>(.*)<\/(del|ins)>\S{0,})(\s|$)/g);
```

Result:

```
Array 
0 " i<del class="del" editid="6">m</del>por<ins class="ins">sss</ins>t<del class="del>a</del>n<ins class="ins">sss</ins>t "
1 " reso<del class="del">ur</del>ce "
2 " develo<ins class="ins">vvv</ins>pers "
3 " integratin<del class="del">g i</del>t "
4 " <ins class="ins">ssss</ins>w<ins class="ins">ss</ins><del class="del">e</del><ins class="ins">ss</ins>bsi<del class="del">te</del>s "
5 " an<ins class="ins">sss</ins>d<del class="del"> </del>customizing "
length 6
```

Comment: It is fine but https://regex101.com/r/cE4mE3/2 in this case it must return 3 matches i.e, you can see here https://regex101.com/r/cE4mE3/3 . In this I have split the content for you to understand better